# How to extract fields from mysql json field order by value

Tags: mysql, sql, json, extract

```sql
| id | json_field |
| 1  | {"a": 1, "b" : 3, "c": 2, "d": -1} |
```

I want to get the *two* fields which have the **smallest** values(I not sure I am expressing clearly), in this case is `a` and `d`.

***Senario***:
given a field, I wanna check if this field is among the two fields which have smallest values in `json_field`, and fetch all results match this condition.

***I wanna implement it by***:
Sort json by value, convert it's fields to an array, and then get the last/first two one.
After I have searched around, I cannot find a way to sort json field by value. I am stuck.

BTW, I am using MySQL5.7.

Comment: Does the complete list of separate properties in JSON object (in shown value these are a,b,c,d) is static and well-known?

Comment: Your json_field is not a valid json, must use double quotes. Please correct.

Comment: *I want to get the two fields which have the smallest values(I not sure I am expressing clearly), in this case is a and d.* What "two fields" you need for `{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}`?

Comment: Oh, three fields share the same value. It rarely happens. If it happens, any two of three is ok.

Comment: What do you mean well-known? These are records which json_field is `null`, but all of leftover have these 4 keys. I named them a,b,c, just for simplicity.